# Recorrer posiciones adyacentes en una matriz

Tags: r, algoritmos, matrices

Quiero sumar los valores adyacentes a un valor. Pongamos el valor M[3,2] el resultado sería 1. En problema no viene tanto de recorrer los casos centrales, sino generar una función rápida que permita recorrer en cualquier punto.

```
    m<-
       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
 [1,]    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    1    0     0
 [2,]    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0     0
 [3,]    1    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0     0
 [4,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
 [5,]    1    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0     0
 [6,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
 [7,]    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    1    0     0
 [8,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
 [9,]    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0     0
[10,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
```

Un saludo,

Answer (score 2):

Asumiendo como en las anteriores respuestas que se buscan los 8 vecinos (verticales, horizontales, diagonales) una aproximación diferentes sería tratar de recrear una lista con todos los vecinos (algo de por sí interesante) y después sumarlos. 
La solución la encontré adaptando el código la última respuesta a esta pregunta: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29105175/find-neighbouring-elements-of-a-matrix-in-r , que me parece genial.

La clave son las distancias entre dos vectores de índices correspondientes a la matriz. Cuando la distancia es igual a 1 son adyacentes. Por ejemplo, `mat[1,1]` tiene distancia 1 con `mas[1,2]`, distancia 2 con `mat[1,3]` y distancia 0 con `mat[1,1]`. Con esa matriz hecha es cuestión de hacer un subset de los elementos en `mat` con distancia 1 con respecto a cada celda.

## Implemetación

```
#Test
mat <- matrix(1:25, ncol = 5)

#todas las coordenadas de mat como pares de índices
grilla <- expand.grid(1:nrow(mat), 1:ncol(mat)) 

# calculo las distancias entre los pares de índices
distancias <- as.matrix(dist(grilla, "maximum", diag=TRUE, upper=TRUE))

#Creo el vector lógico para el subset
#Acá es fácil cambiar el criterio y buscar distancia 3,distancias 0, 1, 2, etc.
distancias_logico <- distancias == 1

#Para cada fila de la matriz de distancias 1 == TRUE hago un subset de la matríz original
#Regresa una lista de largo filas*columnas de mat, en cada una los elementos vecinos.
#Este es un resultado intermedio valioso por sí mismo
lista_vecinos <- apply(distancias_logico, 1, function(i) mat[i])

#Facilmente sumamos los elementos vecinos. 
suma_vecinos <- sapply(lista_vecinos, sum)

#Podemos sacarlo a una estructura de matriz
matriz_suma_vecinos <- matrix(suma_vecinos, nrow=5)
matriz_suma_vecinos[1,1]

[1] 15

#O un data.frame
cbind(grilla, suma_vecinos)
```

No estoy completamente seguro de cuan rápido sea vs. las alternativas. Seguro más lento para un par dado de índices, quizás igual o más rápido para una matriz completa. De todos modos me gusta la idea de encarar el problema por los índices y usar la matriz de distancias para identificar adyacentes.

Comment: Bien ahí @mpaladino y tomo tus palabras **"genial"** incluir la distancia de los valores adyacentes porque se generaliza la pregunta, además al aplicar `apply` y `sapply` se minimiza el uso de los bucles `for` en una matriz que son por definición: [O(n²)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation), asimismo he editado en la parte final mi respuesta para incluir este concepto, pero teniendo en cuenta que la submatriz a sumarse tiene un crecimiento impar: 3x3, 5x5, 7x7,... por cada unidad que aumente la distancia adyacente.

Answer (score 1):

Quisiera aclarar que la convención en muchos lenguajes de programación, para denominar los arreglos [array] (los vectores en el caso de **R** sólo tienen longitud) y las matrices es por: *filas y columnas*: `(N,M), (i,j), (r,c), (row,column)`

```
m[filas, columnas]
```

Teniendo en consideración que se quiere sumar todas las celdas que están "alrededor" de una celda central o pivote (tomando el aporte de @Patricio Moracho), se puede lograr también con subconjunto de matrices:

```
sumAlrededor<-function(m,i,j){
  x<-dim(m)[1]+2 # la matriz aumenta arriba y abajo (filas)
  y<-dim(m)[2]+2 # la matriz aumenta derecha e izquierda (columnas)

  # se genera una matriz de "ceros" con las dimensiones "x por y"
  ceros<-matrix(rep(0,x*y), nrow=x)

  # insertamos en el medio la matriz "m"
  ceros[c(2:(x-1)),c(2:(y-1))] <- m

  # sumamos la submatriz de dimensiones 3x3
  # y le quitamos el valor central
  sum(ceros[c(i:(i+2)), c(j:(j+2))]) - m[i,j]
}
```

Haciendo las pruebas

```
m<-matrix(1:12, nrow=4)
m
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    5    9
[2,]    2    6   10
[3,]    3    7   11
[4,]    4    8   12
```

Testeando todas las combinaciones:

```
for (i in 1:dim(m)[1] ){
  for (j in 1:dim(m)[2]){
    print(paste0("m[",i,", ",j,"]:  ",sumAlrededor(m,i,j)))
  }
  cat("\n")
}

[1] "m[1, 1]:  13"
[1] "m[1, 2]:  28"
[1] "m[1, 3]:  21"

[1] "m[2, 1]:  22"
[1] "m[2, 2]:  48"
[1] "m[2, 3]:  38"

[1] "m[3, 1]:  27"
[1] "m[3, 2]:  56"
[1] "m[3, 3]:  43"

[1] "m[4, 1]:  18"
[1] "m[4, 2]:  37"
[1] "m[4, 3]:  26"
```

## Generalización

Adicionalmente @mpaladino ha incluido una variante interesante cuando la `distancia` entre la celda central y las aledañas es: `1, 2, 3, 4,...`.

En tal sentido, el código usando submatrices incluyendo dicha generalización quedaría de la siguiente forma:

```
sumAlrededor<-function(m,i,j,d=1){
    a<-2*d              # factor de crecimiento de la matriz
    x<-dim(m)[1]+a      # la matriz aumenta arriba y abajo (filas)
    y<-dim(m)[2]+a      # la matriz aumenta derecha e izquierda (columnas)

    # se genera una matriz de "ceros" con las dimensiones "x por y"
    ceros<-matrix(rep(0,x*y), nrow=x)

    # insertamos en el medio la matriz "m"
    ceros[c((1+d):(x-d)),c((1+d):(y-d))] <- m

    # sumamos la submatriz de dimensiones (2d+1)x(2d+1)
    # y le quitamos el valor central
    sum(ceros[c(i:(i+a)), c(j:(j+a))]) - m[i,j]
}
```

> Nótese que cuando la distancia de los valores aledaños es `d=1` quedaría exactamente igual al código inicial.

Si consideramos `m<-matrix(1:12, nrow=4)` con una distancia `d=3` y sumamos los valores aledaños a `m[1,1]` se obtendrá `77` o el equivalente a sumar la matriz `m` restándole `m[1,1]` (dicha celda vale `1`)

```
sum(m)-1 == sumAlrededor(m,1,1,d=3)
# Se imprime: TRUE
```

Finalmente, vale acotar que el código permite hacer las operaciones antes expuestas en matrices de la forma `NxM`, siendo `N` y `M` valores iguales o diferentes.

Answer (score 1):

Entiendo que cuando hablas de valores adyacentes estas hablando de todas las celdas que rodean una en particular, sin contar la celda en cuestión. Por ejemplo, teniendo una matriz como la siguiente:

```
m <- matrix(1:25, nrow=5)
m
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    6   11   16   21
[2,]    2    7   12   17   22
[3,]    3    8   13   18   23
[4,]    4    9   14   19   24
[5,]    5   10   15   20   25
```

La suma de la celda (1,1) sería 15, es decir los valores adyacente serían 6+7+2. La suma de la celda (3,2) sería 64, es decir 2+7+12+3+13+4+9+14. Una forma sencilla de resolverlo sería:

```
sum.adj <- function(m, row, col) {
    m.pad <- cbind(0,rbind(0,m,0),0)
    m.zero <- matrix(rep(0, ncol(m.pad)*nrow(m.pad)), nrow = nrow(m.pad))
    m.zero[c(row, row+1, row+2), c(col, col+1, col+2)] <- 1
    m.zero[row+1, col+1] <- 0 # La celda en cuestión no la sumamos
    sum(m.zero * m.pad)
}

> sum.adj(m, 1, 1)
[1] 15
> sum.adj(m, 3, 2)
[1] 64
```

Para hacer más fácil creamos una versión ensanchada de la matriz original para no preocuparnos con las coordenadas que tocan la parte exterior de la matriz y creamos una matriz de 1  del área que queremos sumar. Luego solo resta multiplicar ambas matrices y hacer la suma.

Comment: Excelente @Patricio Moracho creo que esté es el enfoque correcto, he editado mi respuesta considerando esto, pero lo he implementado con subconjunto de matrices.