# ¿Cómo puedo encontrar las coordenadas de un valor dentro de una matriz?

Tags: r, matrices, r-dplyr

Espero que mi pregunta sea clara.

Supongamos que sabemos que valor está dentro de una matriz, pero no sabemos sus coordenadas; mi pregunta es ¿existe alguna función para saber las coordenadas del dato dentro de la matriz?

Por ejemplo: supongamos que, como en la imagen, sabemos que en la matriz existe el número 25 pero no sabemos sus coordenadas (por la imagen sabemos que es [5,5]), la cuestión sería ¿como llego a esas coordenadas si no las sé?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Para el caso del 25 (un sólo valor) sirve `which(matriz == 25, arr.ind = TRUE)`. Los otros son más complicados (creo), sobre todo el rectángulo rosa.

Comment: @mpaladino, tu comentario bien podría ser una respuesta. Saludos.

Answer (score 3):

Esta respuesta usa la herramienta propuesta por @mpaladino y la amplía para las otras selecciones que marcás:

```
 #repito tu matriz
 mat <- a %*% t(a)

 #Como posteó @mpaladino para un solo valor
 which(mat == 25, arr.ind = TRUE)

 #para valores divisibles exactamente por un número
 which(mat%%7==0, arr.ind = TRUE)

 #En la matriz los números se repiten en distintos lugares, 
 #para el rectángulo violeta, números divisibles por 7 
 # como los mismos valores están en otras posiciones, limitas a la columna 7
 div.7 <- which(mat%%7==0, arr.ind = TRUE)
 div.7[which(div.7[,2] ==7), ]
 row col
  [1,]   1   7
  [2,]   2   7
  [3,]   3   7
  [4,]   4   7
  [5,]   5   7
  [6,]   6   7
  [7,]   7   7
  [8,]   8   7
  [9,]   9   7
  [10,]  10   7

 #Eso podría ser útil para el rectángulo amarillo
 div.8 <- which(mat%%8==0, arr.ind = TRUE)
 div.8[which(div.8[,1] ==8),]
  row col
  [1,]   8   1
  [2,]   8   2
  [3,]   8   3
  [4,]   8   4
  [5,]   8   5
  [6,]   8   6
  [7,]   8   7
  [8,]   8   8
  [9,]   8   9
  [10,]   8  10
 #El cuadrado rosa es un poco más compicado porque los valores se repiten 
 #en otros casilleros de la matriz y no siguen el patrón de ser divisibles, etc. 
 #Por eso para obtener ese rectangulo necesitans info sobre qué parte de la matriz 
 #queres, por ejemplo filas mayores a 3 y columnas mayores a 7

 nrosa <- which(mat>32 & mat <70, arr.ind = TRUE)
 nrosa[which(nrosa[,1]>3 & nrosa[,2]>7),]      

 row col
  [1,]   5   8
  [2,]   6   8
  [3,]   7   8
  [4,]   8   8
  [5,]   4   9
  [6,]   5   9
  [7,]   6   9
  [8,]   7   9
  [9,]   4  10
 [10,]   5  10
 [11,]   6  10
```

Para todo esto necesitas alguna info sobre la matriz, o sobre qué es lo que estás buscando.

Answer (score 2):

Complemento la respuesta de @ichisa con un caso diferente, el de encontrar un número o vector arbitrario dentro de una matriz.

Puede ser que lo que te interese sea encontrar submatrices por alguna característica propia de esa submatriz (múltiplos de 7, de 8, etc.) y en ese caso la respuesta anterior sería apropiada. Si estás buscando encontrar números o filas/columnas arbitrarias aquí van algunas opciones.

La matriz de test es diferente para enfatizar el caso de submatrices arbitrarias. Son números aleatorios entre 1 y 100. No hay un patrón matemático a priori, más que el azar.

```
set.seed(2019)
matriz <- matrix(sample(1:100, 100, replace = TRUE), ncol = 10, byrow = T)
```

### Encontrar solo número

```
which(matriz == 25, arr.ind = TRUE)
```

### Encontrar una fila completa

En este caso del 1 al 10

```
which(apply(matriz, 1, function(x) identical(x, c(25, 42, 69, 17, 61, 76, 19, 26,  9, 90))), matriz)
```

Para encontrar una columna completa simplemente se cambia a 2 el argumento de `apply()`

Los casos para submatrices arbitrarias que no son de 1 x 1, 1 x n o 1 x p son mucho más complicados porque son un problema de topología: te interesan valores vinculados entre sí por una propiedad relacional: la adyacencia. Es decir, no hay nada intrínseco que relacione a esos números, más allá de estar uno al lado de otro.

En [este](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/243009/recorrer-posiciones-adyacentes-en-una-matriz) hilo se trata indirectamente el problema de encontrar submatrices adyacentes. Quizás pueda servir para pensar una solución. Si generas una lista con todas las submatrices del mismo tamaño que la que buscas podrías comparar esa lista con tu submatriz. Con eso al menos podrías saber si la submatriz pertenece a la matriz más grande. Encontrar la posición sería un complicación adicional. Yo no sabría como implementarlo.

También podría servirte investigar librerías de análisis de redes (tipo `igraph::`), que tienen funciones para identificar adyacencias. Aunque uno relaciona al análisis de redes con los gráficos de nodos/enlaces la matemática subyacente se basa en matrices de adyacencia.